# WPF, C# - Por que cuando uso MaterialDesing y trato de agregar mis estilos en el archivo app.xaml ocurre un XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo un proyecto en Visual studio, el cual tiene como Target Net Framework 4.7, el problema es que cuando intento agregar mis estilos en el archivo app.xaml solo puedo agregar un estilo por componente (uno por Button, StackPanel, etc) ya que si agrego dos estilos me arroja el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver tambien estoy usando la libreria de Material Desing, este es mi archivo XAML:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BotonGenerico">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 0 15 0" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0F81E0"/>
                    <Setter Property='BorderBrush' Value="#FF2E6DA4"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                </Style>

               <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="OtroBoton">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 0 15 0" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#000000"/>
                    <Setter Property='BorderBrush' Value="#FF2E6DA4"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion, se debe crear un archivo XAML y agregar como un resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Estilos/Global.xaml"/>
```

En mi caso yo hice una carpeta llamada Estilos en el directorio raiz y dentro de esa carpeta puse el archivo XAML, el codigo de app.xaml quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Estilos/Global.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Estilos/TablaManifiestos.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

el codigo del archivo /Estilos/Global.xaml seria el siguiente:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BotonGenerico" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15 0 15 0" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property='BorderBrush' Value="#FF2E6DA4"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```